# Kubernetes - validate deployments

Tags: kubernetes

I have a namespace `namespace`  - which has ~10-15 deployments.
Creating a big yaml file, and apply it on a "deploy".

How do i validate, wait, watch, block, until all deployments have been rolledout ?

currently i am thinking of:

- get list of deployments
- foreach deployment - make api call to get status
- once all deployments are "green" - end process, signaling deployment/ship is done.

what are the status'es of deployments, is there already a similar tool that can do it? https://github.com/Shopify/kubernetes-deploy is kind of what i am searching for, but it forces a yml structure and so on.

what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Set a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) and use `kubectl rollout status deployment <deployment_name>` to see the `deployment` rollout status

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use Helm for managing deployments. Helm allows you to create reusable templates that can be applied to more than one environment. Read more here: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#getting-started-with-a-chart-template

You can create one big chart for all your services or you can create separate Helm charts for each your service.

Helm also allows you to run tests after deployment is done. Read more here: https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#a-breakdown-of-the-helm-test-hooks

Comment: read about helm, however i am already having my tooling with custom templating and stuff -> resulting in one large yml file. i don't want to introduce yet a another complex thing. but in generall if started from scratch "helm" might be an option. but it boils down to "how do i get the overall status of N deployments"

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `kubectl wait` https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait

It lets you wait for a specific condition of a specific object
In your case:

```
kubectl -n namespace \
             wait --for=condition=Available --timeout=32s \     
             deployment/name
```

Comment: but that would require one `kubectl` per deployement? right?

Answer (score 0):

use --dry-run option in the apply/create command to check the syntax.

Comment: its not about the syntax, i know its correct, `apply`  changes the `image:` which introduces a pull and re-create - which takes time, depending on the size of the change, and i want to know once the "deployment" is done.